# Independently zoom data view without zooming layout view

Tags: arcgis-desktop, layouts

This is probably a really noob question.

How do I zoom in on the data view without it modifying my beautifully positioned layout view? I just want to be able to work with my data zoomed in, but still have the positioning maintained in layout view so I can quickly export again after changes.

I'm sorry if this has been answered before but I couldn't find it in a search.

Answer (score 2):

You could just create an additional data frame in which you edit you data - leaving the other one as is for layout and export.

Comment: Would the symbology and labeling still stay the same though? Or would I have to do that again?

Comment: You can just copy all of the layers from your original data frame and then paste them onto the new data frame.  I think @Phil's solution will work just as well as mine so perhaps try both and see what suits you.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe that you can break the link between your Data View and its Data Frame on the layout.

You could save a bookmark when you have the scale and location you want and use that to get it back.

However, a better solution is probably to use [Magnifier and/or Viewer windows](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00660000043t000000).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am doing that, but here is the problem: When I go back to the data view and do some work, then return to the layout. The view (in layout) of that data frame has been changed to whatever I was looking at in the data view.

Comment: Hmm.. that seems silly! But making bookmarks was the conclusion I came to as well. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I didn't even know about the magnifier and viewer windows. That will work great with my 2nd monitor. Thanks again.